# Debian 9 - rc.local deprecated, how to launch python at startup

Tags: linux, debian, python, rc.local

I am slightly lost, I have a `Debian` 9 server and a `Python` `Flask` script that I am trying to launch at startup.

In the past I have used `rc.local` to launch things at startup but from reading it seems that it is now deprecated.

Can anyone tell me what is its replacement, what method am I best using now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian 9 (like many other current Linux distributions) uses systemd to start and manage your system and services.

You'll be facing a bit of a learning curve compared to adding lines to `rc.local` but writing **unit files** (systemd jargon for what is effectively the equivalent of a start and stop script for a service) will be usefull skill to learn.

The Debian specific documentation on systemd is found on https://wiki.debian.org/systemd
The page https://wiki.debian.org/systemd/Services contains detailed step-by-step intructions for what is needed to write your own (minimal) unit file:

- Create the unit file  "myservice.service"   in the directory `/etc/systemd/system/`

  ```
  # /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service 
  [Unit]
  Description=My Service
  After=network.target

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  Restart=always
  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myservice

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Reload systemd to pick up your changed/new unit files   with: `systemctl daemon-reload`
- Enable and start the new service

  ```
  systemctl enable myservice.service
  systemctl start myservice.service
  ```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that was exactly what I needed. Did some reading up and managed to implement

Answer (score 2):

You launch it using a systemd unit, like every other service.

There are numerous tutorials out on the Internet about how to set this up. Or you can just start with a skeleton unit something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve my project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=you
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/you/project
Environment="PATH=/home/you/project/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/you/project/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no single answer, but you can use something like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/):

> Supervisor is a client/server system that allows its users to monitor
>   and control a number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems.